How to plot a bar graph with a line break in the Y axis in R?
I've been trying to plot a graph in R using the gap.barplot() function in plotrix to add a line break in the Y axis, but it was unsuccessful. I have gone through several questions here on stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything that worked for me. This is the dataframe and code I used -
Condition <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
Value <- c("32", "43", "33", "65", "78", "66", "3", "1.2", "0.8", "2", "1", "1.4")
data1 <- data.frame(Condition, Value)
Since "B" has very low values compared to "A", I wanted to introduce a line break between 44 and 64 as there are no y values within this range.
library("plotrix")
gap.barplot(data1$Value,gap=c(44, 64), ylim = c(0, 80))
I DO get a graph with individual data points on the X axis instead of 2 bars each for A and B, some missing values and an error -
Error in y[bigones] - gapsize : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I need a graph with "A" and "B" on the X axis with two bars and the jitter points of the respective data with a 'p value' and the line break as specified. Is this possible or am I being greedy? Can somebody tell me how this is done? Thank you.

For the bars, do you want the sum of the "A"s and "B"s or the mean, or something else?

Wouldn't the graph be misleading as the bars would not be representative of the values, beating the fundamental purpose of visualising data?
I would suggest either moving b values to a secondary Y-axis, or draw a scatter plot with A values in x-axis and B values in y-axis.

Hi @Edward I need to show that statistically condition A is significantly higher than B (actually this data is from a lab experiment). So the graph must have the mean of A and B on separate bars with their respective data points as jitters and an error bar

Hi @volkang I am trying to show that A is significantly greater than B as in a simple barplot so I don't know if moving B to a secondary axis would help. If you could do it and show me as an answer maybe I will understand. Thanks anyway.


... the graph must have the mean of A and B on separate bars with their
respective data points as jitters and an error bar

You need to calculate the mean values for each group first. I add the size and sd as well to facilitate adding the jittered points and error bars later.
data2 <- aggregate(Value~Condition, FUN=\(x) c(mean=mean(x), n=length(x), sd=sd(x)), data=data1)

library(plotrix)

gap <- c(5,28)

opar <- par(las=1, mar=c(4,4,1,1))

gp <- gap.barplot(data2$Value[,1], 
            gap=gap, 
            ylim = c(0, 56),
            xlim=c(1, 2.5),
            xaxlab=data2$Condition,
            xtics=c(1.5, 2),
            ytics=c(0, 3, seq(30,80,10)),
            ylab="Value", xlab="Condition")

gap.plot(x=jitter(rep(gp, times=c(data2$Value[,2]))),
         y=data1$Value,
         add=TRUE,
         gap=gap, pch=19, col="red")

for(i in 1:2)
  arrows(x0=gp[i], x1=gp[i],
       y0=data2$Value[i,1] - ifelse(i==1, diff(gap), 0), 
       y1=data2$Value[i,1] + data2$Value[i,3] - ifelse(i==1, diff(gap), 0),
       code=3, length=0.05, angle=90)
par(opar)




Hi @Edward, you made and saved my day! Can't thank you enough! The code worked like a charm, I do have two questions for you though, hope you don't mind. I am not well versed in the for loops in R so is there any way to add the error bars without incorporating the for function? Or is it unavoidable for a reason I am unable to understand here? Also, why do we need to add 'xtics' ? A and B are not numerical right?


The for loop is "avoidable" and can easily be replaced by two arrow commands.  2. I added the xtics to get the ticks in the right position. But I should have changed the xlim to c(0.5, 2.5) instead. Then, xtics is not needed.


Hi @Edward, thanks again for the reply. I think I'll simply use your code in the answer for now as I need more time to figure out the arrow() function.

Just copy/paste my arrow() command and replace i with 1 and 2. For the first command, subtract diff(gap). For the second command, ignore the ifelse entirely.

Okay.. Let me try it. Thank you so much.

You get the error because your Value vector contains characters instead of numeric values. You need to use numerical values to insert a gap like this:
Condition <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
Value <- c(32, 43, 33, 65, 78, 66, 3, 1.2, 0.8, 2, 1, 1.4)
data1 <- data.frame(Condition, Value)

library("plotrix")
gap.barplot(data1$Value,gap=c(44, 64), ylim = c(0, 80))
#> ylim 0 80


Created on 2024-09-11 with reprex v2.1.0

Hi @Quinten thank you for the answer, it DID solve the problem with the Error. Could you also tell me how a barplot can be made with just two bars representing the data points from A and B?
